# Prove that if a relation R on a set A is reflexive, symmetric and antisymmetric, then $R=I_A$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, relations

Prove that if a relation $R$ on a set $A$ is reflexive, symmetric and antisymmetric, then $R=I_A$

I know a relation is a set of ordered pairs and that $I_A = (x,x)$ but I have no idea how to do this problem

So $(x,x)R(x,x)$- reflexive

$(x,y)R(y,x)$-symmetric

$(x,y)R(y,x)$ implies $x=y$ -antisymmetric

Comment: I guess i just dont understand what i can assume and what im trying to find

Comment: Do you understand what the problem is asking?

Comment: Start by the definition of reflexive, symmetric, etc... By example: we says a relation R is reflexive if exists xRx.

Comment: I think its the ordered pairs that are confusing me.

Comment: $I_A=(x,x)$ is incorrect. Actually, it should be $I_A=\{(x,x); x\in A\}$. Typeset as `$I_A=\{(x,x); x\in A\}$`.

Comment: $I_A $ is  the relationship such that $x I_A y \if x = y $.  So you need to show that if R is reflexive, symmetric *and* anti symmetric it is that relation.  It's not hard.  x R x because R is relfexive.  If x R y then y R x because R is symetric.  But if x R y  and y R x then x = y because R is anti-symmetric.  So x R y iff x = y.  So R is $I_A $.

Comment: Why the heck is this closed as off topic??? It's a precise question and the op made an effort.  We're being jerks if we don't accept this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to show two separate things:

1. $I_A\subseteq R$, i.e. you need to show that for every $x\in A$ you have $(x,x)\in R$.
2. $R\subseteq I_A$, i.e. you need to show that if $(x,y)\in R$ then $x=y$.

Let $x\in A$, then because $R$ is reflexive we have $(x,x)\in R$, so $I_A\subseteq R$.

Now let $x,y\in A$ and $(x,y)\in R$. Then because $R$ is symmetric you also have $(y,x)\in R$, but $R$ is antisymmetric so if $(x,y)\in R$ and $(y,x)\in R$ then $x=y$.

Hence $R=I_A$.